# zero-width Quine corners

Tags: spacing, symbols, punctuation

I would like to create symbol pairs that

- can be used like quotation marks (spacing-wise)
- look like Quine corners (roughly: `\ulcorner ... \urcorner`) or Japanese quotation marks (roughly: `\ulcorner ... \lrcorner`)
- are zero-width (or of very narrow width)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you use a font that contains Japanese quotation marks? Would a XeLaTeX solution be acceptable?

Comment: @AlanMunn For now I'm sticking to LaTeX because last time I tried XeTeX it didn't interact well with my setup: (1) My (older) version of WinEdt is not Unicode-compatible. (2) XeTeX (very) slightly misplaces the `hyperref`-boxes (around links). (3) It seems to lead to some font errors in the pdf-file (I didn't spend much time trying to fix this). In brief, too much of a trial-and-error curve for me right now. That said, if you are familiar with *those* issues, I'll be all ears.

Comment: You mean that the horizontal bar should go over the delimited text?

Comment: @egreg Ideally the corners are of zero or *very* narrow width but are so high/low that they are unlikely to touch the adjacent letters (while not increasing the line-spacing). Or the horizontal portion of the corners would have to be *very* short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `MnSymbol` fonts have corners that can be used as you'd like

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE10
  <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}

\newcommand{\mnquote}[1]{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}\char#1\relax}

\newcommand{\quinelquote}{\raisebox{.1ex}{\rlap{\mnquote{'036}}\kern.2em}}
\newcommand{\quinerquote}{\/\raisebox{.1ex}{\kern.2em\llap{\mnquote{'043}}}}

\let\nipponlquote\quinelquote
\newcommand{\nipponrquote}{\/\raisebox{-.1ex}{\kern.2em\llap{\mnquote{'055}}}}

\begin{document}
\quinelquote Bcdef\quinerquote

\nipponlquote Bbcdefg\nipponrquote

\nipponlquote Bbcdef\nipponrquote

\end{document}
```

However the problem with `\nipponrquote` is with descenders: this quotation system works with Japanese because its glyphs don't have descenders. The compiled example shows this weakness with the latin alphabet. However the same problem arises when the letter adjacent to the closing "Quine quote" has no ascender.

[image]

Comment: The original `MnSymbol` source code contains the lines `\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}` and `\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{[...]}{}` (with `OMX` instead of `U`). (And an analogous command for the definition of the bold series.) I assume that the departure from this in your solution was intentional?

Comment: @user14996 Yes, it was. The `U` encoding doesn't make any assumption on "character translation".

Comment: This works well in most cases, but not in script style or scriptscript style, where the quotes show up far above the text.  I can make it look okay by wrapping the definitions in `\mathchoice` where the script and scriptscript options actually *lower* the quote characters with their `\raisebox` rather than raising them, but I wonder if you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @MikeShulman Sorry, but this code was meant only for usage in text, not math. For math it's a different story.